# Django print query

Tags: mysql, django, printing, multiple-databases

I'm trying to print the query generated by my queryset by I'm getting this error:

```
print owa_reqs.query
*** OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

The strange thing is that `root@localhost` are my default db credentials, but the `owa_reqs` queryset comes from another db defined in `settings.DATABASES`

*Edit*: The query works, it returns a queryset and if i do `my_queryset.db` it shows the correct db.
Also, i'm using a router that selects the db using a map between app an db in my settings, something like http://diegobz.net/2011/02/10/django-database-router-using-settings/

Comment: Does the query work before? Did you define the database route for it?

Comment: Yeah, the query works, i've defined a router and its working ok too

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some REPL to ran that? Like, if you did a `$ python` command on your terminal and tried to query/print?

If you did that, you should use the `$ python manage.py shell` instead, which will properly connect with your db based on the `settings.py` file.